# Multiple Left Outer Joins with Collections and EF4

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq statement using EF4

```
var q = from a in FunctionA
        from b in FunctionB.Where(a=>a.Id== b.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from c in FunctionC.Where(c=>c.Id== b.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select a;
```

where FunctionA,FunctionB and FunctionC returns Collections.

For some data conditions, i am getting a null exception, since the value of b in  "from b in FunctionB.Where(a=> a.Id== b.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()" is null sometimes and then the statement  "from c in FunctionC.Where(c=>c.Id== b.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()" blows up since b is null.

What would be correct way to do an outer join here ? please help !

Thanks !

Comment: If FunctionB is independent on FunctionA and FunctionC independent on FunctionB the query will most probably create two CROSS JOINS in DB and it will have terrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Where` syntax looks incorrect and I think you are actually using `linq-to-objects`, but all you need to do is add a condition to check Where b is not null

Edit - Based on your comments you want to do this

```
  var q = from a in FunctionA
          from b in FunctionB.Where(x => a.Id == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
          from c in FunctionC.Where(x => b != null && b.Id== x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select a;
```

Comment: Sorry .. i meant to say Where(c=> c.Id== b.Id). I will try your suggestion asap!  Thanks ! Can i use your same syntax you shown above ?

Comment: I am not able to add the condition Where(b != null) !! Is there a different syntax to use ? Thanks !

Comment: i tried  from c in FunctionC.Where(x => b != null && b.Id== x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty() and still causes null reference exception.Looks like its ignoring the not null condition. So im thinking of removing that where clause and join it after i get the final results.